# Eigenvector with matrix amlost full with zeros

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi i have weird problem with calculate eigenvector from simplest matrices. So have something like this:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 2 & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Eigenvalues are : $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = \frac{1}{2}$
So i need calculate eigenvector next:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

The first vector is
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

The second is a problem. From wolfram i'm getting:
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

but from something like this:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

I'm getting $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

The question is which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

You should solve

$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}0.5 & 0 \\ 2 & 0.5\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right] = 0.5\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right] $

That gives 
$ 0.5 x = 0.5x $

$ 2x + 0.5y = 0.5y $

So the only restriction is $ x = 0 $.

You have only 1 eigenvector, and you are not getting 2 because the matrix is defective.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix

Note that the wikipedia page has an example matrix which look very much like yours.

Comment: Let me add that for such defective matrices, one may construct "something" instead of the list of eigenvectors, namely the Jordan normal form. In this 2 times 2 case, one has vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $Au=\lambda u$ is an eigenvector, but $(A-\lambda)v=u$. So the action of $A-\lambda$ on the "not quite eigenvector", the other vector, isn't quite zero, but is equal to the (previous) vector, in this case the eigenvector $u$. So one gets chains etc.

Comment: This generalized Jordan form may be found by special Mathematica functions, see e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JordanDecomposition.html